# livecode urlProgress for mobile download file

Tags: livecode

i am using the bellow code to download a file from my ftp server.The file is downloaded on Mobile devices.
i am try to use a progress bar to show up the amount of data downloaded 
The problem is always i get "cached".
this is my code

```
        constant FTPHOST = "myIp"
    constant FTPUSER = "user"
    constant FTPPASS = "password"
    global sDownloadStart 
    on mouseUp
    put "test.zip" into tFileName
    put "ftp://" & FTPUSER & ":" & FTPPASS & "@" & FTPHOST & "/" & tFileName into pUrl
    -- start the download process, telling Rev to call the "downloadComplete" handler when finished
    Load URL pUrl with message "urlProgress"
    set the startvalue of sb "progressbar" to 0
end mouseUp

on urlProgress pURL, pStatus, pBytesDone, pBytesTotal
    put pStatus into fld "pf1"
    switch item 1 of pStatus
              case "loading"
            set the thumbPosition of sb "Progressbar" to round((pBytesDone / pBytesTotal) * 100)
                     put the round of (item 1 of pBytesDone / 1024)&& "KB Downloaded" into field "status"
                     break
              case "cached"
                 --   if pStatus is "cached" then
                -- work out a file name for saving this file to the desktop
                set the itemDel to slash
                put "binfile:" & specialfolderpath("documents") & "/test.zip" into myPath
                //put "data.file" into tFileName
                put url pUrl into url myPath
                answer "Download completed" with ok
                -- to save memory, now unload the URL from memory
                -- this also means that if you want to run the test again, it does not just use a cached version
                unload pURL
            --end if
                     break
              case "error"
                   if pStatus = "error" or pStatus = "timeout" then
                answer error "The file could not be downloaded." with "ok"
            end if
                     break
              
       end switch

end urlProgress
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `urlProgress`handler is called after the loading of the URL finishes. To get a different status, you have to call another message or call the message in a different way, e.g.

```
on mouseUp
    //delete URL "binfile:" & specialfolderpath("documents") & "/data.file"
    put "data.file" into tFileName
    put "ftp://" & FTPUSER & ":" & FTPPASS & "@" & FTPHOST & "/" & tFileName into pUrl
    -- start the download process, telling Rev to call the "downloadComplete" handler when finished
    // the callback message has only 2 parameters: url and urlStatus
    Load URL pUrl with message "downloadComplete"
    send "urlProgress pUrl" to me in 200 millisecs
end mouseUp

on urlProgress pUrl  //,pStatus, pMessage,pbytesR,pbytesT
    put urlStatus(pUrl) into pStatus
    if item 1 of pUrl is "loading" then
       put item 2 of pStatus into pBytesR
       put item 3 of pStatus into pbytesT
       put item 1 of pStatus into pStatus
       send "urlProgress pUrl" to me in 200 millisecs
     end if
end urlProgress

on downloadComplete theUrl,theUrlStatus
    if theUrlStatus is "cached" then
       -- work out a file name for saving this file to the desktop
       set the itemDel to slash
       put "binfile:" & specialfolderpath("documents") & "/data.file" into myPath
       put "data.file" into tFileName
       put url theUrl into url myPath
       answer "Download completed" with ok
       -- to save memory, now unload the URL from memory
       -- this also means that if you want to run the test again, it does not just use a cached version
        unload pURL
    end if
    -- check if there was a problem with the download
    if pStatus = "error" or pStatus = "timeout" then
        put libUrlErrodData(theUrl) into myErr
        answer error "The file could not be downloaded."&& myErr with "ok"
    end if
end downloadComplete
```

Let me know if this works (it should). If not, I'll have another look.

Comment: Hi mark thank you for the help..the **libUrlErrodData**,and **urlStatus** when i check it in the dictionary work only for desktop and no for mobiles,i have check the code,in the desktop give me only the answer of "download complete" if i produce error i get nothing,in the ios simulator i get nothing ,and the same in the android phone.

Comment: I checked the dictionary again and you're right, there are some problems with those messages. Is there a way for you to know the correct file size? If so, I could change the handlers in my solution.

Comment: yes the file for now is only 400 KB but with records will be more in the future.is a small sqlite file for now with around 800 records

Comment: I have change my code above,i have success with working progress bar and downloaded KB/s int he field..the only problem is when the downloaded file finish i don't get the answer from the line **answer "Download completed" with ok**